# Is it possible to monitor the memory without using any system call in Linux , C language?

Tags: c, linux, memory, monitoring

Is it possible to monitor the memory (memory watcher) without using any system call in Linux , C language?
Am beginner in C and i have searched a lot about it but i couldn't find any solution except using system calls like:

> meminfo
>   , Top system calls.

So the question is, can i access the memory and get information about the process and the usage of memory for each without any system call?
please help.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can get that information from reading files in `/proc`. Reading files does require making system calls, but you don't have to worry about that since C library functions like `open()` and `read()` will make those system calls for you.

Read up on the `/proc` filesystem, experiment with it by `cat`ting files from your shell, then when you are ready to use it in C, Google for a tutorial on how to read files in C using the standard library.

Comment: it sounds like he's talking about caling `system()` when he says *system* calls, based on the question.

Comment: Confusing, since you'd have to use system calls if you don't want to use, er, system() calls.